# PowerShell URI template parsing

Tags: .net, powershell, rest, octopus-deploy, hateoas

I'm looking to use the [Octopus REST API](https://octopus.com/docs/octopus-rest-api) and I wanted to take full advantage of the [HATEOAS links](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api/wiki/Links) that are provided in Octopus REST API and some of them use [URI Templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570).

I found a fairly old post on the Octopus forums [here](https://help.octopus.com/t/any-suggestions-for-uri-template-parsing-in-powershell-for-creating-api-driven-step-templates/10446) but I was wondering with over 4 years passing, if there's a better solution for Uri Template parsing in PowerShell.

If not, I can use a .NET Uri Templating parsing package listed in the forum post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was unable to find any native solutions, but I will share an example that implements [Resta.UriTemplates](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Resta.UriTemplates).

---

```bsh
# Example adapted from: https://github.com/a7b0/uri-templates#examples

Install-Package Resta.UriTemplates -Version 1.3.0

# Import the Resta.UriTemplates assembly
$Path = '.\Resta.UriTemplates.1.3.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Resta.UriTemplates.dll'
Add-Type -Path $Path -PassThru | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Assembly | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName -Unique
# Returns: 
# Resta.UriTemplates, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

$template = [Resta.UriTemplates.UriTemplate]'http://example.org/{area}/news{?type,count}'

Write-Output $template
# Returns:
# Template                                    Variables
# --------                                    ---------
# http://example.org/{area}/news{?type,count} {area, type, count}

$dict = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,object]'
$dict["area"] = "world"
$dict["type"] = "actual"
$dict["count"] = "10"

$template.Resolve($dict)
# Returns: 
# http://example.org/world/news?type=actual&count=10
```